# Configuring newrelic for RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, monitoring, newrelic

I'm configuring newrelic for the first time and in order to configure rewrelic for my Postgres RDS instance, I was going through the instructions:

[image]

However, on my AWS console there's nothing as such `Another AWS account` role type:

[image]

I tried choosing rds-monitoring-role - but there I didn't get another further option for `account ID` etc.. Am I missing anything? Also, I'm on free AWS and newrelic account - can this be a problem as I'm seeing limited options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need an IAM role with a policy including the [permissions listed here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/amazon-integrations/get-started/integrations-managed-policies/):

- rds:ListTagsForResource
- rds:DescribeDBInstances
- rds:DescribeDBClusters

The Roles trust policy needs the following lines inserting:

- `"Principal": {"AWS": "[ACCOUNT_ID]"},`
- `"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"sts:ExternalId": "[EXTERNAL_ID]"}}`

Where `[ACCOUNT_ID]` and `[EXTERNAL_ID]` are replaced with the values above. This allows NR to assume this role to retreive your RDS instance metrics

Comment: Thank you for the response. After this, I was able to see my AWS EC2 instance metrics in newrelic. However, still couldn't see metrics on RDS dashboard. I wasn't even able to find integration for postgres

Comment: The RDS data should be visible under All capabilities > Infrastructure > AWS in the NR console

Comment: thanks. I'm checking here itself. I'm unable to see RDS instances data here. It seems like it didn't import my RDS instances here